# TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined - Deleting from eshop

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get help here.

I'm working on my eshop. All is working fine except removing a object from the cart. When I do it, the price is not changed. And in the console it's written:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined at updateCelkoveCeny (Eshop.js:86)

That 86 row is the row with `parseFloat()`. Any suggestions?

```
function updateCelkoveCeny() {
var produktyKosikContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('kosik-produkty')[0]
var radkyKosik = produktyKosikContainer.getElementsByClassName('kosik-radek')
var celkovaCena = 0
for (var i = 0; i < radkyKosik.length; i++) {
    var radekKosik = radkyKosik[i]
    var cenaElement = radekKosik.getElementsByClassName('kosik-cena')[0]
    var pocetElement = radekKosik.getElementsByClassName('kosik-pocet-input')[0]
    var cena = parseFloat(cenaElement.innerText.replace(',-', ''))
    var pocet = pocetElement.value
    celkovaCena = celkovaCena + (cena * pocet)
}
document.getElementsByClassName('kosik-celkem-cena')[0].innerText = celkovaCena + ",-"
}
```

Edit: This is element, which i add, if user want to add a new product to cart.

```
function pridejPoKliknutiDoKosiku(event) {
var button = event.target
var produkt = button.parentElement.parentElement
var nazevProduktu = produkt.getElementsByClassName('eshop-nazev-produktu')[0].innerText
var cena = produkt.getElementsByClassName('eshop-cena-produktu')[0].innerText
var zdrojObrazku = produkt.getElementsByClassName('eshop-fotka-produktu')[0].src
pridejProduktDoKosiku(nazevProduktu, cena, zdrojObrazku)
updateCelkoveCeny()
 }
 function pridejProduktDoKosiku(nazevProduktu, cena, zdrojObrazku) {
var radekKosik = document.createElement('div')
radekKosik.classList.add('kosik-radek')
var kosikProdukty = document.getElementsByClassName('kosik-produkty')[0]
var NazvyProduktu = kosikProdukty.getElementsByClassName('kosik-nazev-produktu')
for (var i = 0; i < NazvyProduktu.length; i++) {
    if (NazvyProduktu[i].innerText == nazevProduktu) {
        alert("Tento produkt je již obsažen v košíku.")
        return
    }
}
var radekKosikKontent = `
    <div class="kosik-radek">
        <div class="kosik-produktu kosik-sloupec">
            <img class="kosik-fotka-produktu" src="${zdrojObrazku}" width="100" height="100"><br>
            <span class="kosik-nazev-produktu">${nazevProduktu}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="kosik-cena kosik-sloupec">${cena}</span>
        <div class="kosik-pocet kosik-sloupec">
            <input class="kosik-pocet-input" type="number" value="1" min="1">
            <button class="button-remove" type="button">Odstranit</button>
        </div>
    </div><br><br>`
radekKosik.innerHTML = radekKosikKontent
kosikProdukty.append(radekKosik)
radekKosik.getElementsByClassName("button-remove")[0].addEventListener('click', odstranitProduktyVKosiku)
radekKosik.getElementsByClassName('kosik-pocet-input')[0].addEventListener('change', pocetZmenen)
```

}

Comment: Kindly add HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an element in your DOM that contains `class` `'kosik-cena'`? If so, you could loop over the array to get the innerText. Most likely there is no element found with `class` `'kosik-cena'`. This way it is not possible to get the `innerText` of an element that doesn't exist. It would be nice to give some insights into your `HTML`.

Get the `innerText` of an array of elements:

```
var cenaElement = document.getElementsByClassName("kosik-cena");

for (var i = 0; i < cenaElement.length; i++) {
  var text = cenaElement[i].innerText;
  console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: Edited with that, what will be added to cart if user add the product to cart. Please take a look.